# Why the multipart request need to be handled in a different manner than request with other mime type?

Tags: servlets, spring-mvc, mime

I was feeling a little uneasy typing this question as i have been a code monkey for years and never tried to understand why a multipart request needs to be treated differently than that of other requests. I got this question when going through the code of dispatcher servlet in spring web mvc framework. I found there are two different multipart request resolvers one for jakarta commons and another for servlet 3. Can any one please give me a basic idea of the difference between them. I know that we always used to use a file upload servlet to handle the file upload requests in my other projects and other MIME types were handled by a normal servlet.

Answer (score 0):

**The only difference is :**

Serlvet 3.0 is JavaEE standard API which is introduced since Servlet  3.0

Jakarta Commons API was available before Servlet 3.0 was introduced. It is a non-standard API.